# Excel Counting unique values within specific time interval

Tags: excel, count, unique

The name of the file is "Monthly progress (02-2024)", the name of the sheet is "Order" which contains a table A:AH.

Column B= Customers names.

Column Q= the month of purchasing (dd/mm/yyyy).

Column Q includes months since 30/06/2022.

Column S= Order situation (Sold/Failed)

The cell A1= Current month: 29/02/2024

I want to write an equation that counts the number of Unique New buyers who made orders for the first time this month (29/02/2024), excluding the buyers who made orders before and repeated purchasing again this month (29/02/2024).

I tried the following equation but it gives the total number of buyers within the targeted month:

=COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(IF('[Monthly progress (02-2024).xlsx]Order'!$Q$3:$Q$50000=$A$1,IF('[Monthly progress (02-2024).xlsx]Order'!$S$3:$S$20004="Sold",IF(MIN('[Monthly progress (02-2024).xlsx]Order'!$Q$3:$Q$50000)=$A$1,'[Monthly progress (02-2024).xlsx]Order'!$B$3:$B$50000))),'[Monthly progress (02-2024).xlsx]Order'!$B$3:$B$50000<>"")))-1

Herein below, a screenshot from the table

[Sample of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9wloO.png)

Comment: Post some sample data using [Markdown-Table-Generator](https://tabletomarkdown.com/convert-spreadsheet-to-markdown/)

Comment: I added a screen shot as a sample of the table

Comment: You could try: `=ROWS(UNIQUE(FILTER(B:B,MINIFS(Q:Q,Q:Q,A1,S:S,"Sold")=Q:Q)))`

Comment: it gives the same result of my equation